# What is the difference between a quantum mechanical wave and a classical wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, wave-particle-duality

As we know we all say that quantum mechanics is "wave mechanics", and particles are described as waves or associated with every particle a wave nature; the behavior of such waves are described by Schrodinger's equation of motion. However, we already have the classical wave equation for classical waves.

So what makes us to use a different equation for quantum mechanical waves compared to the classical wave? What is peculiar about quantum waves that can not be described by a classical wave equation?!

Answer (score 5):

There are two major differences.

The first difference is that quantum wavefunction is not observable by itself. It only allows you to compute probability distributions for observables.

The other important difference is entanglement. If you need to describe two particles with help of wavefunctions classically you may expect one of two possibilities. On the one hand, you may think that they correspond to some two wavepackets of the single classical field $\Psi(x)$. On the other hand, you may think that they are described by two separate classical fields $\Psi_1(x_1)$ and $\Psi_2(x_2)$. The quantum reality is more interesting - you have to describe them by single wavefunction depending on both coordinates generally not factorizable into to separate pieces $\Psi(x_1,x_2)\neq \Psi_1(x_1)\Psi_2(x_2)$

It may not be very obvious but combined those two traits present huge obstacle (in the form of Bell theorem and its relatives) for trying to dismiss quantum theory as just approximation to some more fundamental classical behaviour.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that a *classical wave* also need not factorize into functions of individual components. The difference is that the quantum "wave" is not the analogon to a classical wave (which would be a field theory), but a classical point particle described by a unique phase space point $(x,p)$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I know it in this way that:" particles at quantum level treat as if they are waves!". is it the same thing as what you say?!!

Comment: @P.A.M It is an often repeated way of putting things which I personally think is rather confusing to the point of being wrong. It's not the **wave** part of quantum mechanics that is different, it's the **compatible marginal distributions cannot exist for all composite state** part, which is what I think was trying to get at, but it has (almost) nothing to do with the use of wavefunctions.

Comment: @G.Bergeron: thanks Bergeron... and may you explain more about the bold part of your text? thanks for help!

Comment: I phrased it in an odd way. I should have said:''Compatible conditional distributions cannot exist for all composite system.'' What it basically means is that you cannot describe the full probability distribution by conditioning on the state of one of the subsystem. This implies a generalization of probability theory which can be described by replacing probability distributions by amplitudes (the wavefunctions). The fact that its evolution is described by a wave equation has to do with locality and galilean invariance and is not the peculiar part of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @G.Bergeron Given that 1) the classical wave transmits energy and 2) the QM wave describes probability, does that mean the QM wave transmit probability?

Comment: @Ooker The classical wave **can** transmit energy, as per the Poynting vector, and likewise, the QM wavefunction can be interpreted as being able to transmit probabilities: see probability current. However, I suggest to take those interpretations with a grain of salt as they can easily lead to erroneous thinking. The really different part of QM is in the use of probabilities the rest is really just a concretization of this. The fact that the equations are not for observables but for the amplitude has fundamental implications, such as the U(1) symmetry of QM which leads to quantum statistics.

Comment: @G.Bergeron what erroneous thinking might I have if the QM wavefunction is interpreted as probability current?

Comment: @Ooker The fact that QM is not about wavefunctions but rather about state vectors. The whole ''wavefunction'' thing adds a lot of, sometimes useful, properties that are not what QM is about. For instance, consider the OPs question...

Answer (score -2):

Classically, every quantity (irrespective whether it is real- or complex-valued) which solves the wave-equation is called a wave. This can e.g. be the electric field, the air-density or the quantum mechanical so-called wave-function.

In quantum mechanics, a particle is described by the wave-function $\psi$, which generally is a complex-valued quantity. The wave-function needn't be a wave (so, the name is a little bit misleading) but it can be a wave.

So, the wave-function in quantum mechanics hasn't much in common with a classical wave. Possibly the name **wave**-function stems from the fact that the wave-function oscillates